# Using async/await with Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, lambda, async-await

I have a method with some code that does an `await` operation:

```
public async Task DoSomething()
{
    var x = await ...;
}
```

I need that code to run on the Dispatcher thread. Now, `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` is awaitable, but I can't mark the lambda as `async` in order to run the `await` from inside it, like this:

```
public async Task DoSomething()
{
    App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(async () =>
        {
            var x = await ...;
        }
    );
}
```

On the inner `async`, I get the error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type.

How can I work with `async` from within `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23442910/1768303) may have introduced an obscure bug. This code:

```
public async Task DoSomething()
{
    App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(async () =>
    {
        var x = await ...;
    });
}
```

uses the [`Dispatcher.Invoke(Action callback)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh199416%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) override form of `Dispatcher.Invoke`, which accepts an `async void` lambda in this particular case. This may lead to quite unexpected behavior, as it usually happens with [`async void` methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
public async Task<int> DoSomethingWithUIAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    this.Title = "Hello!";
    return 42;
}

public async Task DoSomething()
{
    var x = await Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke<Task<int>>(
        DoSomethingWithUIAsync);
    Debug.Print(x.ToString()); // prints 42
}
```

In this case, [`Dispatch.Invoke<Task<int>>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh199389%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) accepts a `Func<Task<int>>` argument and returns the corresponding `Task<int>` which is awaitable. If you don't need to return anything from `DoSomethingWithUIAsync`, simply use `Task` instead of `Task<int>`.

Alternatively, use one of [`Dispatcher.InvokeAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invokeasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods.

Comment: How can I pass a parameter to "DoSomethingWithUIAsync"?

Comment: @Cabuxa.Mapache: `Dispatcher.Invoke<Task<int>>(() => DoSomethingWithUIAsync(param));`

Comment: @Noseratio When you think about why `await Invoke(...)` works it's pretty obvious that it's *exactly* what one wants. I just had to see this example to "get" it. Thanks!

Comment: Particularly good MSDN article you linked regarding the Asyc Best Practices.

Comment: Won't the Debug.Print() call also run on the UI thread, since ConfigureAwait(false) is not used?

Comment: @RobertSchmidt, where `Debug.Print()` will be executed depends on what was the sync. context before `var x = await Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke ...` If there was none, it would be executed on a random pool thread.

Comment: @noseratio Are you certain this is in fact the case? As far as I can tell, since .NET 4.5, `Dispatcher.Invoke` has had an overload that accepts a `Func<Task>`, and the compiler will prefer that to the `Action` overload when compiling code that has an `async () => ...` lambda in it.

Comment: @noseratio https://i.imgur.com/wuUtykM.png

Comment: @JonathanGilbert, I was certain in 2014. The rules about how the most recent versions of C# compiler infer overloads have changed. IIRC, it if a more specific overload is available, it might get precedence. I would still not bet on that, and use `InvokeAsync`.

Comment: That may indeed be the case. The language has changed a lot over the years. The substance of the answer is definitely incorrect today, though. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use below code and then depends of place use it with async and await or without to fire and forget:

```
public static Task FromUiThreadAsync(Action action)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    Dispatcher disp = GetUiDispatcher();
    
    disp.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            action();
            tcs.SetResult(true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tcs.SetException(ex);
        }
    }));

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `Dispatcher.Invoke()`

```
public async Task DoSomething()
{
    App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(async () =>
    {
        var x = await ...;
    });
}
```

Comment: why this answer is downvoted, can anybody explain ?

Comment: The accepted answer explains: "[This form] uses the `Dispatcher.Invoke(Action callback)` override form of `Dispatcher.Invoke`, which accepts an `async void` lambda in this particular case. This may lead to quite unexpected behavior, as it usually happens with `async void` methods."

Comment: @JonathanGilbert what exactly does that quite unexpected behavior mean? Provide some code please.

Comment: An `async void` method does not return the `Task` it has started up, if any. The caller cannot actually even tell whether it is `async`. If you `Dispatcher.Invoke` a `Func<Task>`, then the dispatcher recognizes this pattern and will observe the `Task`, but if you `Dispatcher.Invoke` an `async void`, it's actually running the same `Dispatcher.Invoke` as for synchronous methods. The `async` isn't actually part of the method signature; it's just a method with `void` return type. So, it gets treated as a synchronous method.

Comment: The accepted answer has a link to a page about best practices in async/await, which states: `One subtle trap is passing an async lambda to a method taking an Action parameter; in this case, the async lambda returns void and inherits all the problems of async void methods. As a general rule, async lambdas should only be used if they’re converted to a delegate type that returns Task (for example, Func<Task>).`

Comment: @JonathanGilbert, is this still the case? In modern code, I see a return of Task for this code, and VS identifies it as passing a Func<Task> rather than an Action.

Comment: @Josh It does appear to be the case. I just wrote a simple test app with a method that takes `Action` and a caller that supplies an `async` lambda, and then decompiled the resulting output. It generates a method in the class that has `void` return type and which uses an internal type called `AsyncVoidMethodBuilder`. That in turn leverages some internal generated types including a subclass of `IAsyncStateMachine` that contains the actual body of the `async` lambda.

Comment: @JonathanGilbert, apologies for the confusion, I meant specifically for the Dispatcher.Invoke call discussed here. At a glance it looks like Dispatcher.Invoke(async () => await) correctly uses a Func<Task> overload rather than the Action overload, so at a glance it seems the code in the answer here wouldn't be async void anymore and should work as expected.

Comment: I just made a sample and decompiled the compiler output for good measure and can confirm that you are correct: If the method you are calling accepts both `Action` and `Func<Task>`, then the compiler will call the `Func<Task>` overload -- and `Dispatcher.Invoke` does indeed have both. If the method _only_ has `Action` then you're in `async void` territory, but @noseriato's answer appears to be incorrect, at least with today's C# and supporting libraries. :-)