# Non-blocking dispatcher thread with Control and System.Threading.Thread

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

The problem is that dispatcher blocks the MainWindow thread until it is executed all of the queued AddOutputLine()s. Can these calls be non-blocking for a wpf control?

```
    //TaskPage.xaml.cs
    [MTAThread]
    public void AddOutputLine(string line = "")
    {
        try {
            Session.TaskPage.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate
            {
                txtOutput.Text += "[" + DateTime.Now + "] " + line + Environment.NewLine;
                txtOutput.ScrollToEnd();
            }));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Program.SetCurrentStatus("Error occured : "+ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

In this class that invokes the Action parameter:

```
//BackgroundUploader.cs
private Action<string> _log;
public BackgroundUploader(Client client, Action<string> log = null)
{
    _log = log;
    _client = client;
}
```

while doing this:

```
    //BackgroundUploader.cs
    public void RunThreadProc()
    {
        try
        {
            _log?.Invoke("Timeout interval set for BackGround Task.");
            while (!Stop)
            {
                //the problematic blocking of WPF Control starts here
                var inOutFiles = CreateXML(_sqlStrings, _outputNames, _outputDirectory);
                Send(inOutFiles, _outputDirectory);
                LastRunTime = DateTime.Now;
                _log?.Invoke($"Waiting for {_waitMinutes} minutes...");
                //the Control returns to processing messages
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep((int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_waitMinutes).TotalMilliseconds);
            }
            _log?.Invoke("BackGroundTask canceled.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log?.Invoke($"Error while executing background task: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
```

The RunThreadProc() is called from Control like this:

```
//TaskPage.xaml.cs
_backgroundThread = new System.Threading.Thread(bU.RunThreadProc);
_backGroundThread.Start();
```

I also cannot use Bcl.Async because it's failing on Task result with method that uses async modifier on Windows Server 2003 target OS.

*edit: I encountered the problem inside of the background class, its methods run synchronously, even though they are in a different thread.*

Comment: when you flood the app with messages that will modify a control content which needs a repainting, then yes that will block. You should update the UI only about 25 times per second - as normal human beings will not see any difference ;o)

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/23443359/7740926

Comment: The `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` package was created to allow using `async/await` for precisely such systems (Windows XP, Windows 2003). What was the *actual* problem when you tried using it?

Comment: Apart from that, Windows 2003 is *way* too old and insecure. It reached End of Life in 2015. It's way past time this was replaced by an up-to-date system. This isn't a "yes in an ideal world" situation, this is a "liable for any security breaches and problems" situation. This machine can't connect to any service any more, as all services require TLS algorithms that were never available in Windows 2003

Comment: There are things you can do to improve performance though. A TextBox simply isn't a log file. Modifying the `TextBox.Text` property over and over is simply bad and hugely inefficient coding. No amount of threading can fix this. Use data binding instead to bind the control to a property, and only raise the NotifyChanged event when you really want to update the screen. Even better, use a `List<T>` property and bind a ListView to it. Instead of creating new strings over end over, you'll only need to append items to that List<T>. WPF will only render the visible items too

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, this server is a local virtual machine that's used for a narrow range of tasks, I didn't choose it myself. The  error with Microsoft.Bcl.Async was "System.AggreagteException, at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExceptionHolder.Finilize()" (Source: .NET Runtime, ID 1026, Framework Version: 4.0.30319)

Comment: That didn't come from Bcl.Async, it means one of your tasks threw an exception that was never handled. It's a bug in your application, not Tasks. Had you used a `try` block in your code the exception would be caught. If you used `ContinueWith`, checking for a faulted task would also work. Use tasks instead of manually trying to use threads. They work just fine. Use `Bcl.Async` and eg `await Task.Run`  instead of manually starting threads. That works as well

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I didn't experience this type of exception when I run the application under Windows 10, and even Windows 7.

Comment: Because you don't use just tasks there, you use `await`, which raises any exceptions. In your Windows 2003 code though, you started a task, never called `.Wait()` or `.Result` on it so its exceptions were never noticed, until the GC tried to garbage collect the dead task

Comment: The docs explain how to handle unhandled *task* exceptions, the same way you can handle unhandled application exceptions, to avoid crashing the application

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, the problem with "await" is also the fact that for this particular solution to be successfully compiled and run under Win32 x86 machienes without Win32s API, I use Visual Studio 2010 to create the final assembly, and it has no "await" operator there ...

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5, back in 2012, changed the default behavior and unobserved task exception no longer terminate the application. You'll find a lot of duplicate questions for your real problem, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707295/how-to-handle-all-unhandled-exceptions-when-using-task-parallel-library) Handle the [TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.0) event

Comment: @IvanSilkin don't use VS 2010 then, use VS 2012. This can still target Windows 2003. The real problem is a bug in your code though, not Tasks. Your code throws and never handles an exception. This would crash your application *the same way* any other unhandled exception would

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks for the tip of binding to ListView, I only changed the type of the collection from List<T> to ObservableColletion<T> for the ListView to be notified every time a new row is added. And it solves the problem (at least when starting new threads, without async/await).